# Virtualbox tunnel localhost to windows

Tags: virtualbox

I'm running ubuntu on my laptop but need to be able to test my work in windows xp where I'm using virtualbox. is it possible to tunnel my localhost so that it can be accessed by IE inside virtualbox?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to tunnel. Just request either the IP address of the Ubuntu machine or it's FQN. I use that all the time when doing testing on my machine. Basically Vbox acts as a NAT so if you do an ifconfig and then hit the IP address of the machine you should be good.

Comment: it works just like you describe, thank you for your help

Comment: Hey I am having an issue with this, where I try to hit the ip address but it gives me an oops page... any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the default networking mode (NAT), then the guest can access the host at 10.0.2.2, or via it's 'normal' IP address.

Comment: Using 10.0.0.2 solved my problem with VPNs preventing the normal IP address from being accessed

Answer (score 0):

Virtualbox can see your host machine as just another machine on the network - if that's what you are asking?